# Quarkus equivalent of WildFly/JBoss startup scripts in Keycloak

Tags: dockerfile, keycloak, wildfly, quarkus

So the default distribution of Keycloak has by now [migrated](https://www.keycloak.org/migration/migrating-to-quarkus) from WildFly (JBoss) to Quarkus. Earlier ([containerized](https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak/)) versions supported custom startup scripts in `/opt/jboss/startup-scripts`.

What is their Quarkus equivalent? Should such scripts now somehow form part of the separate build step (`bin/kc.sh build`) and if so, which hooks allow introducing them there? Or is it perhaps just a matter of placing them between `build` and `start` as follows. Is there any specific advice or examples on best practice from upstream?

```
FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak AS builder
WORKDIR /opt/keycloak
RUN /opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh build

# place logic from custom startup scripts here

FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak
COPY --from=builder /opt/keycloak/ /opt/keycloak/
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh"]
CMD ["start", "--optimized"]
```

Answer (score 0):

My initial idea of placing logic from startup script's between `kc.sh build` and `kc.sh start --optimized` turned out to be expedient, although the actual solution turned out to be a bit more involved. This is principally because startup scripts execute at container run-time, whereas `Dockerfile`s "execute" at image build-time.

It now basically looks as follows (in `Dockerfile` and `entrypoint` respectively). As can be seen for the example, the startup scripts had the task creating a realm with a client (and other associated entities).

```
FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak AS builder

WORKDIR /opt/keycloak
RUN /opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh build --health-enabled=true
# ...

COPY --chown=jboss:jboss --chmod=755 entrypoint /opt/keycloak/bin/
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/keycloak/bin/entrypoint"]
CMD ["start", \
  "--optimized", \
  "--https-certificate-file", "/usr/local/keycloak/tls.crt", \
  "--https-certificate-key-file", "/usr/local/keycloak/tls.key" ]
```

```
/opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh $@ &

while ! curl --head -fsS https://$KC_HOSTNAME:8443/health/ready > /dev/null 2>&1; do
  sleep 1
done

config=$(mktemp)
/opt/keycloak/bin/kcadm.sh config credentials \
  --config $config \
  --server https://$KC_HOSTNAME:8443 \
  --realm master \
  --user $KEYCLOAK_ADMIN \
  --password $KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD

/opt/keycloak/bin/kcadm.sh create realms --config $config ...
/opt/keycloak/bin/kcadm.sh create clients --config $config ...
# ...

wait
```